# Tailwind postcss nesting is not working with nested scss codes

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, tailwind-css, postcss

I am trying to use scss but tailwind is not compiling as expected.

Thats how i build application.css

```
"build:css": "tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css"
```

Here is my application.scss;

```
@import 'application_dock/colors.scss';
@import 'application_dock/pages/spots.scss';

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans';
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
```

Spots.scss;

```
.spots {
  .spot {
    color: blue;

    .spot-content {
      @apply h-32;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the built css file output;

```
.spots {
  .spot {
    color: blue;
    .spot-content{
      height: 8rem;
    }
  }
}
```

I expect it to be like;

```
.spots .spot {
  color: blue;
}
.spots .spot .spot-content {
  height: 8rem;
}
```

My postcss.config.js;

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'postcss-import': {},
    'tailwindcss/nesting': {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {}
  },
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feels like an unspoken configuration:

```bash
$ tailwindcss -h                                                   
...
Options:
...
       --postcss            Load custom PostCSS configuration
```

```bash
$ tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.scss

Rebuilding...
.spots {
  .spot {
    color: blue;
    .spot-content {
      height: 8rem
    }
  }
}
```

```bash
$ tailwindcss --postcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.scss

Rebuilding...
.spots .spot {
  color: blue;
}

.spots .spot .spot-content {
  height: 8rem;
}
```

Just update `package.json` and add `--postcss` option, it also takes an optional path to *postcss.config.js*:

```
"scripts": {
  "build:css": "tailwindcss --postcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.scss -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css"
}
```

---

Also, consider making a *spot* helper/component/partial and avoid extra css and unnecessary nesting:

```html
<!-- app/views/spots/_spot.html.erb -->
<div class="w-32 h-32 rounded-full grid place-content-center <%= color %>">
  <div class="text-white"> <%= text %> </div>
</div>
```

Literally spent 10 minutes playing with spots:

```rb
<div class="grid gap-2 grid-cols-[repeat(auto-fit,8rem)]">
  <% colors = %w[bg-blue-500 bg-red-500 bg-indigo-500 bg-purple-500].cycle %>
  <% 36.times do |i| %>
    <%= render "spots/spot", text: "i'm a spot ##{i}", color: colors.next %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, i never saw that configuration anywhere. Also will consider your suggestions about spots, thanks a lot!

Comment: This helped me alot as I was trying to pass tailwind config to postcss and failed. But letting tailwind handle postcss instead worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

After installing `postcss-cli` and building with `postcss` fixed the issue/

```
"build:css": "postcss ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss -o ./app/assets/builds/application.css"
```